# How to remove layout information from dot file?

Tags: graphviz, dot

There is a much large dot graph file that has been layouted using dot. I wonder how to remove such layout information as `bb, pos` and etc, to restore its orginal content before layout?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would write a perl script that cut out everything that wasn't a

`node [ attribs... ]

edge [ attribs ... ]

*some node id* -> *some other nodeid* `

Which leaves you your

1. Connectivity information
2. Node, edge labels, attributes

Just remember to cut out the pos attributes, etc, or find a layout option in sfdp or dot that forces an ignore.

This is not that hard to do so even if you are not Perliterate you should be able to pick it up pretty simply.

Comment: Yes, the layout information can be removed by regex. Is there any method to do it by dot command?

Answer (score 0):

Try dot with [`canon`](http://graphviz.org/content/output-formats#dcanon):

```
dot -Tcanon gwithlayout.gv -o nolayout.gv
```

The output should be a pretty-printed version of your graph without layout information (can't test on mobile...).

Comment: Thank you, but dot -Tcanon can't do it.